# How can I build my program with py2app without getting an error?

Tags: python, tkinter, setuptools, py2app

I'm trying to write a simple python app with Tkinter and building it with py2app.

my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
APP = ["main.py"]
OPTIONS = {
    "argv_emulation": True,
    "iconfile": "icon.png"
}
DATA_FILES = ["Cute-Penguin-icon.png", "data.json", "data.txt", "icon.png", "main.py", "usernames.txt"]

setup(

    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],

)
```

When I run `python3 setup setupy.py` I get the final message DONE!

But when I'm trying to run my app, an error comes and I can only terminate the process.

I found that you should first run the command like `python setup setup.py -A`, so it creates various folders within list folder. Then I should be able to run the app from the terminal with `$ dist/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp`, (with the appropriate file names of course) but I get [Errno] no such file or directory. I'm guessing it happens because after building in my dist folder there is nothing, only main.py, so there is no /Contents/MacOS/... to open.
Theoretically I should get an error log from this command which I can debug my program with, but I can't do that for mentioned reasons.

I've been trying to solve the problem for days, and still can't so I'm quite desperate. Can you help me out pls?

Comment: What is the error that comes up? Please add it to the question (not a comment). Use a code block so the formatting will be preserved.

Comment: You probably forgot to list a resource in the `DATA_FILES` section